# Calling setState causes React to throw infinite re-renders error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was unable to track down the problem, it might be something with the async function or the useEffect hook. If I uncomment the following code I get these errors.

**Quizzical.js**

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function Quizzical() {
    const [quizzState, setQuizzState] = React.useState([])

    async function getQuestions() {
        let response = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5")
        let data = await response.json()
        return data;
    }

    function prepareQuestions(data) {
        let objectArray = []

        data.map(item => {
            let answersArray = []
            item.incorrect_answers.map(ans => answersArray.push(ans))
            answersArray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * answersArray.length), 0, item.correct_answer)
          

            objectArray.push({
                answers: answersArray,
                question: item.question,
                correct: item.correct_answer,
                chosen: null
            })
        })

        return objectArray
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getQuestions().then(data => setQuizzState(prepareQuestions(data.results)))
    }, [])

    
    function setAnswer(id, answerID) {
        let obj = quizzState[1]
        console.log(obj)
        // setQuizzState(prev => {
        //     return [...prev]
        // })
    }

    function answerClicked(id, answer) {
        console.log(id, answer)
    }

    setAnswer()

    return (
        <div className="quizzical-app">
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Error Message**
[image]

If I keep it commented this is what the console shows:
[image]

Comment: It is because of calling `setAnswer` on the top level of the function component. What exactly should `setAnswer` do?

Comment: setAnswer needs to change one element of the object array

Comment: I want to pass it down  later,  so a child component can change the state of the parent

Comment: you probably want to call that when the user does something, calling it before returning the JSX is causing the infinite loop

Comment: I called it in the top component just to test that it works

Comment: oh nice, I put it on a button, now it seems to be solved.